# Why is my jQuery .click() function not working? I'm stumped

Tags: jquery

After reading several similar posts without finding a solution, I'm asking a question to hopefully resolve my frustration.

Below is the Object output on cosole.log() I'm trying to click.

```
Object { 0: a#addressSelect2571765.addressLink, length: 1, prevObject: {…} }
​
0: <a id="addressSelect2571765" class="addressLink" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/giveaway/enter_choose_a…/326698?address=2571765">
​
length: 1
​
prevObject: Object { 0: HTMLDocument https://www.goodreads.com/giveaway/enter_choose_address/326698-firekeeper-s-daughter?ref=giv_enter_cta, length: 1 }
​
<prototype>: Object { jquery: "3.6.0", constructor: S(e, t), length: 0, … }
```

I have tried several variations:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include      *www.goodreads.com/giveaway*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(#addressSelect2571765).click();
    
});

OR

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(a.addressLink).click();
    
});

OR

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(a:contains('select this address')).click();
    
});
```

Every attempt failing for just this object.  I'm able to .click() other objects on the next screen.  So, I'm not sure why this instance isn't working.

I don't post often, if I've left out any pertinent information let me know. I'll be glad to provide.   Thank you in advance for any and all advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add selector under quotes.

Example: $('#addressSelect2571765').click()

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it did not click the link.  I normally have no problems getting .click() to work.  That's why I'm so frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution, but I don't know why it makes a difference.  From a previous script, I used the following function to perform .click().

```
function clickGiveaway(selector)
{
    var x = $(selector);
    if (x.length > 0)
    {
        x[0].click();
    }
}
```

Next, I called that function using the following.

```
clickGiveaway('a.addressLink');
```

Any insight why this might solve the problem I was having?